# Parallelization of unit and integration tests in springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to parallelize tests in my spring boot application. For this, I have made the changes in the maven surefire plugin to include the parallel argument with classes as value and thread count argument with 5 as value. But when I run maven clean install, `mvn clean install` I get PessimisticLockingFailure or Pessimistic Exception.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>classes</parallel>
        <threadCount>5</threadCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For my test cases, I have configured H2 database in the application properties file present under the test folder. After reading on google I found out that I need to include `MVCC=TRUE;DEFAULT_LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000` in the database url. So, therefore the application properties file has below configuration:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:h2:TestDB;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MVCC=TRUE;DEFAULT_LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000
    jpa:
        database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedH2Dialect
        database: H2
        open-in-view: false
        show-sql: true
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
            naming:
                physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
                implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
        properties:
            hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
            hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: false
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate
            hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC
```

Now I understand, that this Pessimistic lock is being done because it should be in order to follow ACID properties. Also what I understood that in the case of concurrency H2 uses pessimistic locking instead of optimistic locking, which makes sense as we do not want in corrupt data. But then how do I parallelize my tests. I also see that while executing these tests maven uses different threads, as the thread name is printed, but then I get this Pessimistic Exception.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PessimisticLockException: could not execute statement
    at com.x.y.z.repository.a.ProductionDataRepositoryTest.setUp(ProductionDataRepositoryTest.java:45)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: 
Timeout trying to lock table ; SQL statement:
insert into my_table
```

One thought that came to my mind is that maybe, we should run individual h2 instances per thread, that if there are 4 threads then 4 h2 instances, but then wouldn't it be expensive, and if not then how to do that?
Or is there some other approach in achieving parallelization of tests in spring boot, java and maven.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: This means you have integration tests and not unit tests....The question how a unit/integration tests looks like....On the first glance this means you can't parallelize your tests...It alway depends on your test code and also on your application code...

Comment: can I then run the integration tests sequentially and unit tests in parallel in the same build?